# Angularjs Radio Buttons in Nested ng-repeat not checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a html template with one ng-repeat nested inside a parent ng-repeat. The parent ng-repeat contains radio button where the user can select 'Satisfied' or Unsatisfied' which correspond to values 1 and 0 respectively. If a user selects Unsatisfied, a detailed list of options is displayed so they can select more radios for further info. Here's the html;

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="group in Groups">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="{{group.Id}}" ng-model="group.SatisfactionLevel" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="{{group.Id}}" ng-model="group.SatisfactionLevel" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="group-detail" ng-class="{'hidden': group.SatisfactionLevel != 1}">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in group.Details">
            <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
            <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.SatisfactionLevel" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.SatisfactionLevel" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The json returned from the server looks like this;

```
"Groups": [
        {
            "Id":"AA",
            "Description":"Service",
            "SatisfactionLevel":1,
            "Details":[{"Id":"AA1","Description":"Cleanliness","SatisfactionLevel":1},
                       {"Id":"AA2","Description":"Timeliness","SatisfactionLevel":1}
                      ]
        },
        {
            "Id":"AB",
            "Description":"Food",
            "SatisfactionLevel":1,
            "Details":[{"Id":"AB1","Description":"Price","SatisfactionLevel":1},
                       {"Id":"AB2","Description":"Portion","SatisfactionLevel":1}
                      ]
        }          
      ]
```

Everything works except that the radio buttons in the nested ng-repeat are not checked. I can see in fiddler that the Satisfactionlevel property contains values. Anybody see where I'm going wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE**

There was really nothing wrong with the code. It turns out different items in `Groups` can contain the same `Details` items. Since I'm using `name="{{item.Id}}"` for the name attribute, other radios in other group details with the same name but different values were causing previous radios with the same name to get unchecked.
This was my fix;

```
<td><input type="radio" value="1" name="{{group.Id}}-{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.SatisfactionLevel" /></td>
```

since group ids are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have the same value in both `input`s - I'm guessing this is a typo?

Second, if you use `value="1"`, it is interpreted as a string `"1"`, but your model is an integer `1`.

Instead, use `ng-value`:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="0" name="{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.SatisfactionLevel">
<input type="radio" ng-value="1" name="{{item.Id}}" ng-model="item.SatisfactionLevel">
```

Comment: The group radios in the outer ng-repeat work so I don't think it's an issue of string vs integer. U tried ng-value and it didn't work

Comment: @MosesMachua, here's your code with `ng-value` in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb0mgsgx/) - what doesn't work?

Comment: @MosesMachua, did you get your answer? What hasn't worked in a fiddle that I provided in the comment?

Comment: Sorry @New Dev. I didn't. I saw your fidddle and it's still not explainable why it works on the fiddle and not on the actual code. I have to look at it more later and update.

Comment: @MosesMachua, then you question is not complete since it cannot on its own repro the error

Comment: i found the problem was that child ids which are used for the name attribute of the radio were not unique - meaning that even if a child id was unique in that group, another group could have a child with the same id hence radio buttons were not working right.

Comment: @MosesMachua, yes, it's always better to "namespace" your inputs

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted even though it wasn't the direct solution but it led me to investigate more and find the problem.